# Need help in an Sql Query

Tags: mysql

I have a fee Table. Whenever a student paying fee it will store in this table.

```
feeid student_id paid_date  received_amount balance_amount next_due_date
    3          1 2015-11-07               1000          15000 2015-11-01
    5          2 2015-11-07               2000          14000 2015-11-02
    9          3 2015-11-07               30000          15000 2015-11-07
   11          1 2015-11-07            1000          14000 2015-07-11
   12          4 2015-11-07               1000          40000 2015-11-07
   13          4 2015-11-07            1000          39000 2015-12-01
   14          3 2015-11-07            1000          14000 2015-11-30
   15          5 2015-11-09               1000          25000 2015-11-09
   16          1 2015-11-09            5000           9000 2015-11-30
   17          2 2015-11-09            1000          13000 2015-11-15
   18          6 2015-11-10               1000          20000 2015-11-10
   19          1 2015-11-11            1000           8000 2015-11-11
   20          4 2015-11-11            1000          38000 2015-11-11
   21          7 2015-11-11               1000          24000 2015-11-11
   22          8 2015-11-11               1000          19500 2015-11-11
   23          1 2015-11-14            1000           7000 2015-11-16
```

So there are more than 1 entries for a single single.I need every students fee details(only last paid details)

Comment: Checkout https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Still struggling after reading that? What would the desired result look like?

Comment: And why are there 0 amounts?

Comment: What would the desired result look like? Also, don't store 'balance_amount'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM table t1
    WHERE paid_date=(SELECT MAX(t2.paid_date)
                  FROM table t2
                  WHERE t1.student_id = t2.student_id);
```

Comment: i need to display only the latest fee details row of every students..this will not do that

Comment: thanks for improve my answer . i update my answer :) - @Strawberry

Comment: Good. But note that an uncorellated subquery is likely to be orders of magnitude faster than a corellated one.

Comment: Of course, this returns multiple rows where students make multiple payments on the same date - but the OP hasn't clarified what should happen in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

1. First get all the unique student ids.
2. After that in a loop

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE student_id = studentIdFromLoop ORDER BY feeid DESC LIMIT 1
   ```

This will give you the last fee record of the every student.